# Error fetch_assoc en PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tengo un problema al intentar obtener un dato de mi `DB`. Acabo de empezar a utilizar `PDO` para mis conexiones.
Estoy haciendo una consulta, pero me salta el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc() in...

```html
  $userNameSession = $_SESSION['username'];
  $u_e_id_sql = "SELECT u_empresaID FROM usuarios WHERE u_email='$userNameSession'";
  $u_e_id_result = $conn->query($u_e_id_sql);
  $u_e_id_rows = $u_e_id_result->fetch_assoc();
  $u_e_id_show = $u_e_id_rows['u_empresaID'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he arreglado de la siguiente forma

```
  $u_e_id_rows = $u_e_id_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```